# How to get additional resources without buying or finding them

Tags: godus

After playing on the godus beta for a while I have noticed that it is rather hard to come by certain resources that I require. I have looked at different ways of obtaining resources. the main ways i know of is:

1. Finding them in hidden chests
2. Buying them from the menu
3. Doing challenges / Multiplayer

I know as the game is in beta there may not be any functionality to obtain them at the moment but if anyone knows a way in which I could obtain more resources I would be very grateful if you could tell me how

Answer (score 3):

The general consensus is that you need to play multiplayer to gain some resources to move on.  If you were extremely lucky, managed the cards really well and managed your gems well you can purchase what you need.

- Purchase cards in the book = Go to the resources section of the cook and click the gem.  ~30 gems per card.  You must close the book after purchases to receive them.
- You don't want to find the cottages card until you have finished mining.
- Lastly you can find some people who will describe how to edit some configuration(s) to gain gems, etc.
- But the design is to play some multiplayer, this is the large shrine with the handshake.  The winner will get some random resource cards.

If you got the game from Steam, then the Steam community forums are about the only place to get information.  Also follow [22Cans twitter](https://twitter.com/22Cans) feed for updates.